# How do I add the output from point code to my Swift OSX Project?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, paintcode

If I create an object in paint code I, am then either given a style sheet or code from the tab section.

Stylesheet:

```
import Cocoa

public class StyleKitName : NSObject {

    //// Drawing Methods

    public class func drawMain() {
        //// Color Declarations
        let color = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        //// Rectangle Drawing
        let rectanglePath = NSBezierPath(rect: NSMakeRect(29, 30, 198, 166))
        color.setFill()
        rectanglePath.fill()
    }
}
```

Code from tab:

```
//// Color Declarations
let color = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

//// Rectangle Drawing
let rectanglePath = NSBezierPath(rect: NSMakeRect(29, 30, 198, 166))
color.setFill()
rectanglePath.fill()
```

How do I then go about importing this into my swift project. I have tried putting the style sheet in a separate `.swift` file then calling the function from my `viewDidLoad` function in the `NSViewController` by doing: `var rectangle = StyleKitName.drawMain()` but nothing appeared on the NSView. I also tried pasting the code from the tab directly into the view controller's view did load but nothing appeared on the view controller.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit lost in the woods with regard to creating a custom view.

1) StyleKitName must inherit from `NSView`. Read the NSView class reference.

2) To define how a custom view paints itself, you must override `drawRect()`, not define your own function.

3) To cause a view to paint itself, you must not call `drawRect()` directly, but instead call `setNeedsDisplayInRect()`

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setNeedsDisplayInRect:

4) viewDidLoad() is not the proper place in the ViewController lifecycle to be calling drawing functions. If instead you *layout* your custom view within your main view by using `addSubView()` within `viewDidLoad()`, you won't need to initiate any drawing requests. You're supposed to do the layout at load time, define *how* a view should be drawn at compile time, and let OS X decide *when* to redraw it at run time.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html